# count() doesn't give me the right value?

Tags: php, mysql, count

This code gives me the error :

> Notice: Undefined offset: 1 in ...

But in my SQL table, there is only one row in the "name" column.

```
    $teams = mysql_query("SELECT name FROM teams");
    $teams = mysql_fetch_array($teams);

    for($i = 0; $i < count($teams); $i++){
        echo $teams[$i];
    }
```

Comment: Please post information to your table

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you use mysql_fetch_array it only returns the first row from your query. You'll have to loop through your teams like this:

```
$teams = mysql_query("SELECT name FROM teams");

while($team = mysql_fetch_assoc($teams)) {
    echo "<pre>";
    print_r($team);
}
```

I would also strongly advice to switch to mysqli instead of mysl as it is depricated!

Comment: Err, hasn't OP stated there's only one row? In any case, the way they have it should still do something, albeit printing out the _columns_ of the first row.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to look at "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM teams"